# Making strings for filter condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter

I want to make string variable which has many variables inside it so I want to join / construct it dynamically and pass the variable to the filter function of Arrays.

```
const mytuple = thisobj => thisobj.location === value ;
```

I want to construct the above variable `mytuple` to be used below

```
let myresult = datasource.filter(mytuple);
```

I am doing the following but I get the error saying `Delhi is not a function`

```
var keys = new Array("location");
var values = new Array("Delhi");
const finaltuple = join(keys, tuples);
let myresult = datasource.filter(finaltuple);
console.log(myresult);

function join(keys, values) {
  var  joincondition = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      joincondition += "thisobj." + keys[i] + "===" + '"' + tuples[i] + '"';
  }
  return joincondition;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to recreate the function call with a string??? That is not gong to happen with a string.

Comment: Constructing an array with the `new` keyword is rarely a good idea. You could say `var values = []; values.push("Dehli");` to make an empty array and add the string "Dehli" to it.

Comment: thanks I will keep note of this

Answer (score 0):

You can not create a string and expect the js engine to know it is JavaScript code. You should be making a function that does the checks. So alter your code to be a function and it loops over your object and sees that it matches.

```
var filters = [["location", "Delhi"], ["foo", "bar"]];
const check = obj => filters.every(req => obj[req[0]] === req[1])
let myresult = datasource.filter(check)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer .I will get into the detail of this code.

Comment: let totalPrice = myresult.reduce((acc,next) => acc + next.Demand, 0);             
How to make the next.Demand dynamic